# Scala number of occurences of element in list of lists

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

To make it simple, let's imagine I have the following input:

```
List(List("A", "A"), List("A", "B"), List("B", "C"), List("B", "C"))
```

How would it be possible to group the elements inside the lists in such fashion so that I would know how many lists are they in. For example, following the output of a *mapValues* function just to illustrate what I mean, the result of the previous input should be something like:

```
Map("A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 2)
```

Just to be sure I made clear what I mean, a way to interpret the result would be to say that *"A"* is present in 2 of the sub-lists (regardless of how many times it appears inside of a particular sub-list), *"B"* is present in 3 of the sub-lists and *"C"* is in 2. I just want a way to map how many different sub-lists each of the individual elements are present in.

Comment: @XavierGuihot that just counts how many times each letter appears, not what was asked.

Comment: @nmat that's what I was going to say, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding performance, this would work:

```
val list = List(List("A", "A"), List("A", "B"), List("B", "C"), List("B", "C"))
val elements = list.flatten.distinct
elements.map(el => el -> list.count(_.contains(el))).toMap
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, still adjusting to my solution, but for the simplification given, it works wonders, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fold` operation to like this

```
list.flatten.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int])((map, word) => map + (word -> (map.getOrElse(word,0) + 1)))
//scala> res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(A -> 3, B -> 3, C -> 2)
```

Comment: Not the desired result. This counts total occurrences of each "word", which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: The fact that even for a simple case like the one I provided the output differs from yours shows that what you proposed is not what I'm looking for. Thanks anyways!